# iterate day wise with ptime

Tags: c++, date, boost, timezone, timestamp

I wan't to iterate day by day in a for loop. I created a Boost `ptime` that represent a day like '2012-01-01 00:00:00' at my local time. (Germany)

It currently looks like this `(ptime start_t, ptime end_t):`

```
for( posix_time::ptime i = start_t; i < end_t; i += gregorian::days(1) ) {
    ...
}
```

The date 25.10.2009 has 23 hours because of the switch between the daylight saving times. But the command `gregorian::days(1)` adds 24 hours.

Does anyone have a good solution to iterate day-wise by involving the time zone without generating my own timezone database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer!

It helped me a lot and I also got a good solution from a coworker: the boost::locale methods and classes.

It's pretty easy to get the correct local timezone with these namespace.

For further information: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html

Example:

```
for( boost::locale::date_time i = start; i.time < end; += period::day(1) ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a simple day iteration, you can use the `day_iterator`. However, as far as I know, the Gregorian Date System of boost is agnostic to DST (DST is a property of *time*, not of *date*). Similarly, the Posix Time System "defines a non-adjusted time system". I think the Local Time System is appropriate for your task.

Example:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    // POSIX time zone string for Germany
    //local_time::time_zone_ptr zone( 
    //  new local_time::posix_time_zone("CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3") );

    // load from a database
    local_time::tz_database db;
    db.load_from_file("path_to_boost/libs/date_time"
                          "/data/date_time_zonespec.csv");
    local_time::time_zone_ptr zone = db.time_zone_from_region("Europe/Berlin");

    local_time::local_date_time ldt =
        local_time::local_sec_clock::local_time(zone);

    posix_time::ptime pt = posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

    while(true)
    {
        ldt += gregorian::days(1);
        pt += gregorian::days(1);

        std::cout << "local_date_time: " << ldt << '\n';
        std::cout << "ptime:           " << pt  << '\n';

        std::cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

*Note:* I don't know how to get the time zone from the user's / system's settings, nor could I find a reliable source for the POSIX time zone string. There's the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html) plus what wikipedia says, but better you check it yourself.

Thanks to [Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) for pointing out a mistake in the POSIX time string and providing the alternative solution via a database.

Comment: Actually for POSIX time zones, the sign is reversed, so it's `CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3`.  But you'd be better off using `time_zone_database` in Boost with the IANA standard zone of `Europe/Berlin`

Comment: @MattJohnson Hmm I got wrong results for the negative sign, I'll check again. Thanks for the hint with `time_zone_database`, I'll look into that, too.

Comment: Yeah, POSIX zones can be rather limiting.  I wrote about them briefly in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: @MattJohnson I get correct results for the negative sign now.. weird. Thanks for the corrections!